# Angular 14: Error: A collection and schematic is required during execution

Tags: angular, typescript, collections, components, angular-schematics

I am trying to learn angular.  I installed the lastest version and created an app called test using `ng new test` command.

Then I opened the app in visual studio code.  In the terminal I entered the following command to create a new component:
`ng g form1`

I get the following error:

```
Error: A collection and schematic is required during execution.
```

Please see the screenshot.
Please help.  Thanks.

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuakV.png)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

https://angular.io/cli/generate

A schematic is the type of object you want to create, such as a service, pipe, directive, or component.

In this instance, you're providing the name of what you want to generate ('form1') but not what kind of object.

You could run `ng g c form1` to generate a form1.component, or `ng g s form1` to generate a form1.service.

Answer (score 2):

The command is wrong.
Please try to use the command below.

```
ng g c "MODULE-NAME"
```

Here `g` is for generate and `c` stand for component.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you are using

```bash
ng g form1
```

watch this issue **"Error: A collection and schematic is required during execution."**

You can not use only

```bash
ng g form1
```

Specify the module using the `--module` parameter.
For example, if the main module is `app.module.ts`, run this:

```bash
ng g c new-component --module app
```

Comment: brilliant! this was my issue

Answer (score 1):

The correct format is `ng <action> <schema> <path/filename>`

In your case you are probably trying to `generate` a `component` which could be something like:

`ng generate component form1` or

`ng g c form1` (shorthand)